# Expo auth not working in Production build, working fine in Development build

Tags: react-native, expo-auth-session

My **expo auth not working when i publish it to expo**, when i download it, its only showing google prompt and redirecting, and doing nothing, not updating the Auth token, nor fetching any data.
**however its working absolutley fine in development build**

```
 ` const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState();
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState();
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState();
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
    androidClientId:
      "xyc",
    iosClientId:
      "xyc",
    expoClientId:
      "xyc",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (response?.type === "success") {
      setAccessToken(response.authentication);

      const persistAuth = async () => {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(
          "auth",
          JSON.stringify(response.authentication)
        );
      };
      persistAuth();
    }
  }, [response]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPersistedAuth = async () => {
      const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem("auth");
      if (jsonValue != null) {
        const authFromJson = JSON.parse(jsonValue);
        setAuth(authFromJson);

        let userInfoResponse = await fetch(
          "https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me",
          {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${authFromJson.accessToken}` },
          }
        );
        userInfoResponse.json().then((data) => {
          setUserInfo(data);
        });

        setRequireRefresh(
          !AuthSession.TokenResponse.isTokenFresh({
            expiresIn: authFromJson.expiresIn,
            issuedAt: authFromJson.issuedAt,
          })
        );
      }
    };
    getPersistedAuth();
  }, [response]);`
```

i tried to update my scheme in app.json
here is my app.json.

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "deliveroo",
    "slug": "deliveroo",
    "version": "1.2.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "scheme": "com.hammadsohaill786.project",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0,
      "url": "xyc"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.hammadsohaill786.project"
    },
    "android": {
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "com.hammadsohaill786.deliveroo"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "xyc"
      }
    },
    "plugins": [
      "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin"
    ],
    "runtimeVersion": {
      "policy": "sdkVersion"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIXED***

anyone having a similar problem, make sure to set proxy to false ( promptAsync({ useProxy: false, showInRecents: true }) ), note it may not work on your development Expo GO app, but it will work on your EAS build, which was the issue right?

```
  <TouchableOpacity
        className="bg-[#00CCBB] text-white py-1 px-3 items-center justify-center rounded-xl"
        onPress={
          auth
            ? logout
            : () => promptAsync({ useProxy: false, showInRecents: true })
        }
        title={auth ? "Logout" : "login"}
      >
        <Text
          className={`${
            auth ? "text-black font-bold" : "text-white font-bold"
          }`}
        >
          {auth ? "Logout" : "login"}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: This gives me the following typescript error: `'useProxy' does not exist in type 'AuthRequestPromptOptions'`